# "DIR *759*" does not return files with 759 in the name. Is this a Windows 7 issue?

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt, dir

I just opened a command prompt and did a:

```
DIR *759*
```

To my surprised, it did not return files containing 759 in the name.

Here are the results:

> 56CheckRegister_0710.RTF
>   c5e64017_2007-09-30.pgp
>   C5X87050_200601.PRT
>   c5e64017_2008-09-30.pgp
>   K6CheckRegister_0110.RTF
>   K6CheckRegister_0910.RTF
>   K7CheckRegister_1108.RTF
>   K7CheckSummary_1299.RTF

Should this DIR work?
I could have sworn it worked before but I have not done this since upgrading to Windows 7.
Is this a Windows 7 issue?

**Edited:** Dwidle was correct. It is picking up the DOS 8.3 Name. Using the DIR /x returned the short name in the first column.

```
561759~1.RTF 56CheckRegister_0710.RTF  
C52759~1.PGP c5e64017_2007-09-30.pgp  
C54759~1.PRT C5X87050_200601.PRT  
C5A759~1.PGP c5e64017_2008-09-30.pgp  
             c5p75922.prt  
             c5p75978.prt  
K63759~1.RTF K6CheckRegister_0110.RTF  
K64759~1.RTF K6CheckRegister_0910.RTF  
K75759~1.RTF K7CheckRegister_1108.RTF  
K7C759~1.RTF K7CheckSummary_1299.RTF`
561759~1.RTF 56CheckRegister_0710.RTF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's finding the short name, the old dos 8.3 name that's generated from the long name.  use the /x switch to see the short name as well and I bet they will have 759.

This will get files with 759 in the long name.

```
dir *759* /b | findstr /M 759
```

Answer (score 1):

I can do that as well

```
C:\Users\ALAIN>doskey dir=dir

C:\Users\ALAIN>dir *759*
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s'appelle Acer
 Le numéro de série du volume est 12D1-55F6

 Répertoire de C:\Users\ALAIN

22/02/2011  22:25    <REP>          .
22/02/2011  22:25    <REP>          ..
22/02/2011  22:24               877 56CheckRegister_0710.RTF
22/02/2011  22:24               938 c5e64017_2007-09-30.pgp
22/02/2011  22:24             1 056 c5e64017_2008-09-30.pgp
22/02/2011  22:24               995 C5X87050_200601.PRT
22/02/2011  22:25             1 118 K6CheckRegister_0110.RTF
22/02/2011  22:25             1 180 K6CheckRegister_0910.RTF
22/02/2011  22:25             1 242 K7CheckRegister_1108.RTF

               7 fichier(s)            7 406 octets
              13 Rép(s)  79 641 792 512 octets libres

C:\Users\ALAIN>doskey dir=

C:\Users\ALAIN>dir *759*
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s'appelle Acer
 Le numéro de série du volume est 12D1-55F6

 Répertoire de C:\Users\ALAIN

Fichier introuvable

C:\Users\ALAIN>
```

Please also look at other less pleasant possible explanations

1. A "pirate alias" (can be defined in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\App Paths`
2. A rootkit (see sysinternals rootkit detector)

Comment: The possible explanations are eclipsed by the fact that this is Windows _working as designed_.

Answer (score 0):

This is Windows NT *working as designed*, and as it has worked for a long time.  This behaviour is widely known.  There are no rootkits or "pirate aliases" involved.

[As I wrote over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/238900/winxp-dir-command-3-and-4-char-extensions-are-the-same/248976#248976), where [another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/238900/winxp-dir-command-3-and-4-char-extensions-are-the-same/238930#238930) talks about changing system settings to stop this from happening *further* than it already does, this varies according to what command interpreter's `DIR` command one uses.  The [`DIR` command in Take Command](http://jpsoft.com./help/dir.htm), for example, [only matches long names by default](http://jpsoft.com./help/lfnsearch.htm) and so doesn't exhibit this behaviour. ([Matching of short as well as long names can be turned on](http://jpsoft.com./help/index.htm?wildcards.htm#sfn) for compatibility with CMD's `DIR` command.)  So there are ways to address this that don't require `FSUTIL` and administrator privileges.